# Parse Facebook Login failed for Facebook developer account iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I created a Facebook login for one of my iOS app. The app is not submitted for Review but I want to test it by using different developer accounts. Now, I can only login as Administrator or only one of my developer can login. All other developers, I added failed to login. All Facebook developer accounts are verified. Anybody know the reason, please help me.

Comment: Do you have any stack traces? Any error messages been shown on login?

Comment: There is no trace. The FBGraph object is not giving permission to developer to login and access facebook data. Application simply quits.